# Salvar na Memoria EEPROM do arduino

Tags: arduino

Estou querendo fazer um projeto de fechadura controlada por Smartphone. Basicamente, o usuário tem a opção de mudar a senha pelo Keypad, Mas quero que a nova senha(String) seja salva na memoria Interna do Arduino (EEPROM), Só que to apanhando aqui pois se trata de uma string...Se tiverem uma solução ou qualquer ajuda já conta bastante. Segue o código abaixo.

```
 #include <Keypad.h>
 #include <EEPROM.h>
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

 /*-------------------------------KEYPAD---------------------------------------*/
 const byte numRows= 4; //number of rows on the keypad
 const byte numCols= 4; //number of columns on the keypad
 char keypressed;
 char keymap[numRows][numCols]=
       {
       {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
       {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
       {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
       {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
  };
 byte rowPins[numRows] = {13,12,11,10};//linhas 0 até 3
 byte colPins[numCols] = {9,8,7,6};//Columas 0 até 3 
 Keypad myKeypad= Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);

 /*-------------------------------VARIAVEIS------------------------------------*/

 int rele = 2;
 LiquidCrystal lcd (A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5);
 String password="2017"; //SENHA ATUAL
 String tempPassword=""; //VARIAVEL PARA GUARDAR NOVA SENHA
 int doublecheck;    //VERIFICAR 2 VEZES A NOVA SENHA
 boolean armed = false;  //ESTADO ATUAL(ARMADA :TRUE / DESARMADA:false)
 boolean input_pass;   //SENHA (CORRETA:true / ERRADA:false)
 boolean storedPassword = true;
 boolean changedPassword = false;
 boolean checkPassword = false;
 int i = 1; //VARIAVEL PARA CONTROLE DO VETOR
 /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

 void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   lcd.begin(16, 2);
   pinMode(rele, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(rele, LOW);
   lcd.setCursor(0,0);
   lcd.print("PROJETO PI");
   lcd.setCursor(0,1);
   lcd.print("   LOCKPICK  ");
   delay(2000);
   lcd.clear();

 }

 void loop() { //LOOP PRINCIPAL
   unlockTheDoor();
 }
      /********************************FUNCÕES*************************************/

 void unlockTheDoor(){
   lockAgain: //goto label
   tempPassword="";
   i=6;
   digitalWrite(rele, LOW);
   lcd.clear();
   while(!checkPassword){
     lcd.setCursor(0,0);
     lcd.print("ABRA A PORTA  ");
     lcd.setCursor(0,1);
     lcd.print("SENHA>");
     keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();   //Ler as teclas precionadas
     if (keypressed != NO_KEY){    //Accept only numbers and * from keypad
  if (keypressed == '0' || keypressed == '1' || keypressed == '2' || keypressed == '3' ||
  keypressed == '4' || keypressed == '5' || keypressed == '6' || keypressed == '7' ||
  keypressed == '8' || keypressed == '9' ){
         tempPassword += keypressed;
         lcd.setCursor(i,1);
         Serial.println("*");
         lcd.print("*"); 
    i++;  
  }
  else if (keypressed == 'A'){
    //Serial.println("MUDAR SENHA");
    lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
     lcd.print("MUDAR SENHA"); 
     delay(1000);
    changePassword();
    goto lockAgain;
  }
  else if (keypressed=='#'){
    lcd.clear();
    break;
  }
  else if (keypressed == '*'){ 
    //CONFIRIR SENHA
    if (password==tempPassword){//SE FOR CORRETA...
      lcd.clear();      
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("SENHA CORRETA");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("PORTA DESBLOQUEADA");
      Serial.println("opened");
      digitalWrite(rele, HIGH);//CODIGO DA PORTA AQUI
      delay(8000);
      goto lockAgain;
    }
    else{           //CASO FALSO, TENTE NOVAMENTE
      tempPassword="";
      Serial.println("SENHA INCORRETA");
      delay(5000);
      goto lockAgain;
    }
  }
}
   }
 }     

 //Change current password
 void changePassword(){
   retry: //label for goto
   tempPassword="";
   lcd.clear();
   i=1;
   while(!changedPassword){        //AGUARDANDO PELA SENHA
keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("SENHA ATUAL");
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print(">");
if (keypressed != NO_KEY){
  if (keypressed == '0' || keypressed == '1' || keypressed == '2' || keypressed == '3' ||
  keypressed == '4' || keypressed == '5' || keypressed == '6' || keypressed == '7' ||
  keypressed == '8' || keypressed == '9' ){
    tempPassword += keypressed;
    lcd.setCursor(i,1);
    lcd.print("*");
    i++;     
  }
  else if (keypressed=='#'){
    break;
  }
  else if (keypressed == '*'){
    i=1;
    if (password==tempPassword){
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Senha Confirmada");
      delay(1000);
      lcd.clear();
      storedPassword=false;
      newPassword();          //Se a senha estiver certa, chama a função newPassword
      break;
    }
    else{               //tente denovo
      tempPassword="";
      goto retry;
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
 String firstpass;
 //DENIFIR NOVA SENHA
 void newPassword(){
   tempPassword="";
   changedPassword=false;
   lcd.clear();
   i=1;
   while(!storedPassword){
     keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();   //LER AS TECLAS
     if (doublecheck==0){
       lcd.setCursor(0,0);
       lcd.print("INSIRA NOVA SENHA");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(">");
}
else{
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("CONFIRME SUA NOVA SENHA...");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(">");
}
if (keypressed != NO_KEY){
  if (keypressed == '0' || keypressed == '1' || keypressed == '2' || keypressed == '3' ||
  keypressed == '4' || keypressed == '5' || keypressed == '6' || keypressed == '7' ||
  keypressed == '8' || keypressed == '9' ){
    tempPassword += keypressed;
    lcd.setCursor(i,1);
    lcd.print("*");
    i++;
  }
  else if (keypressed=='#'){
    break;
  }
  else if (keypressed == '*'){
    if (doublecheck == 0){
      firstpass=tempPassword;
      doublecheck=1;
      newPassword();
    }
    if (doublecheck==1){
      doublecheck=0;
      if (firstpass==tempPassword){
        i=1;
        firstpass="";
        password = tempPassword;
        tempPassword="";//APAGAR SENHA TEMP
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("SENHA TROCADA");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("----------------");
          storedPassword=true;
          delay(2000);
          lcd.clear();
          break;
      }
      else{
        firstpass="";
        newPassword();
           }
         }
      } 
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta já tem um tempo, mas vou responder para ajudar quem encontrar este tópico.

Como a quantidade de dados é inferior a 1kb (limite da memoria a ser manipulada no chip atmega328), você pode usar a bibilioteca:

```
 #include <EEPROM.h>
```

Com os métodos:

```
 EEPROM.write()
 EEPROM.read()
```

Leia a documentação em: https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/EEPROMLoadAndSaveSettings

Mas fique atento que a gravação e leitura é feita em byte e não em string.

Encontrei este código em: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=430656.0

Não testei, mas no fórum diz que funciona.

```
void save_string_to_eeprom(char *stringIn){

  Serial.print("stringIn length: ");
  Serial.print(strlen(stringIn));
  Serial.println();

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(stringIn); i++){

      EEPROM.write(i, stringIn[i]);

  }

}

void read_string_from_eeprom(char *bufferIn){

  Serial.print("bufferIn sizeof: ");
  Serial.print(sizeof(bufferIn));
  Serial.println();

    for(int i = 0; i < eeprom_size; i++){

        bufferIn[i] = EEPROM.read(i);

    }

}
```